# python struct unpack length error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a bytes object with length 41. I tried to unpack it with:

```
struct.unpack('2B2B32sBi',data)
```

But I got a error that:

> struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 44

I think the length of `2B2B32sBi` should be `2*1+2*1+32*1+1+4=41` after check the python document. Why am I wrong?

Comment: unpack must have a buffer of the **exact** right length for the format, excess is an error, so you must truncate/slice to unpack early info like variable lengths and then create a new format than encompasses them, like: format2 = format1 + str(len) + 's'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just encountered *padding* since you've got bytes data first, and then integer (which has stronger alignment constraints)

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

> Padding is only automatically added between successive structure members. No padding is added at the beginning or the end of the encoded struct.

So you *have* to specify an endianness to disable padding:

```
struct.unpack('<2B2B32sBi',data)
```

**Edited for completeness**, after reading Galen's excellent answer: just specifying `=` is better if you don't want to force endianness.

Answer (score 3):

See the parts of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) regarding alignment:

> By default, C types are represented in the machine’s native format and byte order, and properly aligned by skipping pad bytes if necessary (according to the rules used by the C compiler).

> Native size and alignment are determined using the C compiler’s sizeof expression. This is always combined with native byte order.

> Note the difference between '@' and '=': both use native byte order, but the size and alignment of the latter is standardized.

To illustrate this:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.calcsize("2B2B32sBi")
44
>>> struct.calcsize("@2B2B32sBi")
44
>>> struct.calcsize("=2B2B32sBi")
41
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read the first note in the [struct documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) again.
Default is C-aligned data boundaries, so some padding bytes are responsible for the difference. So adding the appropriate byte order should fix the problem.