# struct.unpack() struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 124 bytes

Tags: python, struct

I have a socket client communicating with a python socket server

The client is sending packets in chunks of 112 bytes, here is how I attempt to unpack it from server side

```
self.unpacked = struct.unpack("i f f f f f f f f f i f i f f f f f f B f f B f f B f f B f f", msg)
```

And I have the following error:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 124 bytes
```

Here is what msg looks like:

```
b'\xcf\xff\xff\xff\x01\x00|D\x07\x01\xc4B\x01\x00\xc8C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?P\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

It has a length of 112

And if I calulate the total size of the types in struct.unpack args

I get

```
i f f f f f f f f f i f i f f f f f f B f f B f f B f f B f f
4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+1+4+4+1+4+4+1+4+4+1+4+4
== 112 bytes
```

My question is why does unpack requires a buffer of 124 when the args only specify 112 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

[python struct unpack length error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750056/python-struct-unpack-length-error/47750278#47750278)

So I had to change

```
"i f f f f f f f f f i f i f f f f f f B f f B f f B f f B f f"
```

to

```
"<i f f f f f f f f f i f i f f f f f f B f f B f f B f f B f f"
```

Because "B" (1 byte) requires it

[python struct unpack length error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750056/python-struct-unpack-length-error/47750278#47750278)